# Combining conditional logic with inoremap in .vimrc

Tags: vim

Hi guys I just need a quick fix if you could: using Vim and I need my curly brace to close automatically when the opening bracket is typed. I have `inoremap { {<CR>}<ESC>ko` which is working fine. However I need to disable this when it is not necessary. So I was thinking a simple if-statement looking for a ')' as the previous character would suffice. However, I am not sure how I should do this here. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by calling a custom function.

## Preliminaries

- `:help getline()`:

  > getline({lnum} [, {end}])
  >
  > Without {end} the result is a String, which is line {lnum} from the current buffer. When {lnum} is a String that doesn't start with a digit, line() is called to translate the String into a Number. To get the line under the cursor: getline(".")
- `:help col()`:

  > col({expr})
  >
  > The result is a Number, which is the byte index of the column position given with {expr}.

So you can get the character right before the cursor by `getline('.')[col('.') - 2]`.

- `:help feedkeys()`:

  > feedkeys({string} [, {mode}])
  >
  > Characters in {string} are queued for processing as if they come from a mapping or were typed by the user. By default the string is added to the end of the typeahead buffer, thus if a mapping is still being executed the characters come after them.
  >
  > To include special keys into {string}, use double-quotes and "..." notation expr-quote. For example, feedkeys("\<CR>") simulates pressing of the <Enter> key. But feedkeys('\<CR>') pushes 5 characters.
  >
  > If {mode} is absent, keys are remapped. {mode} is a String, which can contain these character flags:
  >
  > ```
  > 'm'     Remap keys. This is default.
  > 'n'     Do not remap keys.
  > ```
- `:help i_CTRL-O`, `:help i_CTRL-\_CTRL-O`:

  ```
  CTRL-O          execute one command, return to Insert mode   i_CTRL-O
  CTRL-\ CTRL-O   like CTRL-O but don't move the cursor        i_CTRL-\_CTRL-O
  ```

## The Function

First of all, `ko` can be reduced to a single command `O`.

```
function! s:InsertBrace()
  let l:last_char = getline('.')[col('.') - 2]
  if l:last_char ==# ')'
    call feedkeys("{\<CR>}\<Esc>O", 'n')
  else
    call feedkeys('{', 'n')
  endif
endfunction
inoremap { <C-\><C-O>:call <SID>InsertBrace()<CR>
```

Whenever we press <kbd>{</kbd>, we call `s:InsertBrace()`. The function checks the character under the current cursor. If that is `)`, then we insert `{<CR>}<Esc>O`, note the escapes. Otherwise, we just insert single `{`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer there is a lot of useful information here!

Answer (score 1):

The following should do it:

```
inoremap { <c-o>:call InsertCurly()<cr>

function! InsertCurly()
    normal! gi{
    if search(')\s*\%#')
        exe "normal! o}\<esc>ko \<bs>"
    endif
endf
```

Note the space and `\<bs>` at the end of the `exe` command, whichs lets you keep the auto-indent that was created.

There are also good plugins to auto-close brackets, but you have to look at them to check if it can be conditionnal.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be exactly what you are looking. But Instead of writing a function, hence not making complex vimrc. A simpler but somewhat labourous approach that I use

Escape the mapping using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>  whenever you don't want the mapping